# Set Language from Alert for Android (XAMARIN Studio)

Tags: c#, android, mobile, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am building an app where user can select which Language he wants to set when the app starts. A pop up will show "Select your Language" with two buttons one for Arabic and the other one for English.

The problem is that when I change the locale and execute this line

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
```

the app broke. there is no error or any exception but all controls stop capturing the events. I tried to declare an Intent using this and this.Class and when I call StartActivity it is like restarting the whole app and the pop comes again to select the language. I am new to android development as I spent my last two years working on SAP Abap so I might ask a stupid question :D

here is my code

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Khums
{
    [Activity (Label = "Khums", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            int r = Resource.Layout.Main;
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            var languageIso = "ar-SA";

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
            //alert.SetTitle ("Selected Language");

            AlertDialog alertDiaog = alert.Create ();
            alertDiaog.SetTitle ("Select Language:");

            alertDiaog.SetButton ("العربية", (s, EventArgs) => {

                languageIso = "ar-SA";
                var locale = new Java.Util.Locale(languageIso);
                Java.Util.Locale.Default = locale;
                var config = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration{Locale = locale };
                BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config, BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
                //base.SetContentView(r);
                //Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.Class);
                //StartActivity(intent);

                SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            });

            alertDiaog.SetButton2 ("English", (s, EventArgs) => {

                languageIso = "en-US";
                var locale = new Java.Util.Locale(languageIso);
                Java.Util.Locale.Default = locale;
                var config = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration{Locale = locale };
                BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config, BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
                SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            });


            alertDiaog.Show();

            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

            RadioButton rb_FirstTime = FindViewById<RadioButton> (Resource.Id.radioButton1);
            RadioButton rb_Regular = FindViewById<RadioButton> (Resource.Id.radioButton2);

            EditText ti_lyearBalance = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.ti_lastBalance);
            EditText ti_Balance = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.ti_Balance);
            EditText ti_Clothes = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.ti_Clothes);
            EditText ti_Food = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.ti_Food);
            EditText ti_Perfumes = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.ti_Perfumes);
            EditText ti_Subscriptions = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.ti_Subscriptions);
            EditText ti_Others = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.ti_Others);

            TextView lbl_lyearBalance = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.lbl_lastBalance);

            rb_FirstTime.Click += RadioButtonHandler;
            rb_Regular.Click += RadioButtonHandler;
            button.Click += MyButtoHandler;
        }

        private void RadioButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void MyButtoHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private double calculateKhumus (double[] amounts, Boolean isRegular)
        {


        }

        private void LangSwitchHndler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

can you please show me what I'm doing wrong here. I tried to use togglebutton instead of alert and also standard button but ends up with the same issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved after trying for two days. All I did is to create a menu and change the target framework to Android 3.1 Honeycomb. Then I just start the activity and everything is working fine.

So the issue was only target framework!